# BigQuery - finding unicode characters

Tags: unicode, google-bigquery

Im looking to build a query that will find records that have unicode characters in a given column.

I've tried variations on

```
SELECT col 
FROM [project:dataset.table] 
where (REGEXP_MATCH(path,r"[\u0020-\u007E]"))
```

Can't seem to get the proper syntax for the regex. This particular one gives the error:

> Failed to parse regular expression "[\u0020-\u007E]": invalid escape sequence: \u

Reading [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string-and-bytes-literals) it would seem to imply that double quotes should enable unicode escapes. Apparently not.

Suggestions?

---

### Edit:

Data is (roughly) of the form

- timestamp
- record id
- array [

  - data fraction a
  - data fraction b ]

Imagine that I want to find records where *any* of **data fraction a** contains unicode characters. Does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below - for/with BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT col 
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, '''[\u0020-\u007E]''')
```

> Imagine that I want to find records where any of data fraction a contains unicode characters.

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS col, ['ab!"#$%&()*+,-./', 'cd!"#$%&()*+,-./'] AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['12,3', '456', '789'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['abc']
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, '''[\u0020-\u0030]''')) 
  FROM UNNEST(path) AS path 
) > 0
```

Comment: This is cool but (unf) the column in question is part of an arrayed datatype. This query won't work with that. Didn't think it would matter but I don't know how std sql deals with that.

Comment: @ethrbunny - see updated answer with example of what I believe is what you ask now